# html5 canvas testing and selenium python bindings

Tags: python, html, selenium, canvas

I have a webserver which I am trying to test. From what I am told, it is written in HTML5 with a canvas. If you try to view the source for the login page, you see very little.  If you "inspect element" (using Chrome) and poke around, you find this:

```
<form id="loginForm">
```

That is what I want to locate using selenium.  I am using the selenium python bindings.  So, for example, I can do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://192.168.144.92:9000")
print(browser.title)
assert 'MyTitle' in browser.title
print(browser.title)
```

Everything works just fine for the above code.  When I try to locate the login form, I use the following line:

```
x = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm')
```

I am getting a standard exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n
```

Why can I not locate this form?

Comment: more likely a timing issue

Comment: I put a sleep in before calling a method on the object and it works fine now.  Also, I switched from accessing the form to its data entry fields.  I can answer my own question if it makes sense....

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch onto an `iframe` in which your `form` maybe is present and then locate your `input tag`.

```
#Will switch to the iframe
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("frame_id"))
#Locate your form
form = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginForm")))
```